# Calculate one column values dynamically on click of checkbox using oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

When you select checkbox then  selected transaction should be added to Total field , similarly when unchecked then selected transaction should be subtracted from Total field

In Oracle Form Builder, I kept one checkbox and total field value should get calculated whenever the checkbox clicked.

Comment: I think you should share with us what have you tried so far literally to be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

That would be `WHEN-CHECKBOX-CHANGED` trigger that looks like this:

```
if checkbox_checked('block.checkbox_item_name') then
   :ctrl_block.total := nvl(:ctrl_block.total, 0) + :block.selected_transaction;
else
   :ctrl_block.total := :ctrl_block.total         - :block.selected_transaction;
end if;
```

`NVL` is here to avoid problems when there's no total (yet). See if you can remove it (that depends on total's initial value).

Comment: It works for single record only.. i have more than 10 records in the block(mulit-record block). Total column is in control block. Whenever checkbox select and deselect total column should get updated.

Comment: WHEN-CHECKBOX-CHANGED trigger should be in multi-record block. Is it? Other than that, it *should* work.

Comment: So in the code shown, just change ":block.total" to ":control_block.total".  Using your actual block and field names, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
if checkbox_checked('multi_record_block.checkbox_item_name') then
   :Control.total := :Control.total + :multi_record_block.selected_transaction;
else
if :Control.total <> 0 then
   :Control.total := :Control.total - :multi_record_block.selected_transaction;
End if;
end if;
```